# How do I load an image in PHP

Tags: php

I want code that loads an image to a PHP server and then send it to browser.

For example I want `sample.php` to send an image to browser once it is requested.
in other words, I want to create a PHP file that acts like a proxy for an image.

Comment: This is not a real question yet. Where is the image supposed to come from? How do you want to load it to the server? And at which point do you want to serve it back?

Comment: So, something aside from an `img` tag, or a redirect to the image's location on the server?

Comment: Anyway, this is going to be interesting for you: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: @Pekaa: image will come from a url like 'hxxtp://google.com/sample.jpg'

Comment: @backdoor - are you asking how to output html to display the image or literally output the image file itself. It doesn't seem like you really need PHP at all unless you want to create some kind of automatic way for the images to get on your server

Comment: As a side note, it is best on this site to use a descriptive title, such as "How do I load an image in php" rather than "question about php".  Your title should enable other users to quickly get a gist of the question when scanning questions to look at.

Answer (score 1):

why are you doing this?
why don't deliver the image directly? 
if you are trying to display a random image you may as well just redirect to the image using

```
header("Location: address-of-image");
```

for delivering the file to your clients from your server and not from its original location you can just do. however your php.ini settings need to allow external file opens

```
readfile("http://www.example.com/image.jpg")
```

correct headers are not required if you are going to display the image in an img tag,
altough i would recommend it. you should check the filetype of the image or in most cases just set an octet-stream header so the browser doesnt assume an incorrect type like text or something and tries to display binary data.
to do so just do

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream")
```

one more thing to consider may be setting correct headers for caching...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
$image = fopen("image.png");  
Modify the headers(not sure exacly if it's correct)
headers("Content-type: image/png");  
And then send the image  
echo fread($image, file_size("image.png"));
```